# How can I match a word that contains 3 or more numbers in regex?

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove a word from a string if it contains 3 or more consecutive numbers and it is the first word in the string?

I think i will need the replaceFirst() function but i am not sure about the regex

eg.

Hello world one two. --> no change

**H931llo world one two. --> world one two**.

Hello world 112 one two --> no change

**edit:** consecutive numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex will only match words at the beginning of the string if that word contains at least three consecutive digits:

```
^\w*\d{3}\w*
```

`\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, and usually letters from other languages if a Unicode option is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The regex:

```
^[A-Za-z]*\d{3}\d*[A-Za-z]*
```

Comment: He said 3 or more consecutive digits. That's for the 'more'.